# C# how to extract part of string

Tags: c#

how can I extract a part from string with "-" separated between the characters?
for example, I want to extract "123" from "123-4567-9012"
or extract "4567" from  "123-4567-9012"
or even 9012 from the same string

Comment: you van use `Substring`, or you can `Split` and get them with array..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just split on the `-` character and later you can access them. Use [string.Split(char[])](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx)

```
string str  = "123-4567-9012";
string[] arr = str.Split('-');
```

it will result in:

```
arr[0] = "123";
arr[1] = "4567";
arr[2] = "9012"
```

Answer (score 3):

Probably more effective if you need only first occurrence:

```
var str = "123-4567-9012";
var substr = str.Substring(0, str.IndexOf('-'));
```

Answer (score 3):

If you String.Split, you can break a string into separate parts, based on a delimter. For example, using:

```
var input = "123-4567-9012";
var parts = input.Split('-');
foreach(var part in parts)
  Console.WriteLine(part);
```

Will output:

```
123
4567
9012
```

You can do the opposite with String.Join- for example.

```
var result = String.Join("-", parts);
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Will output:

```
123-4567-9012
```